# Pop up background color not covering entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I created a pop up window and the background color of it that darken the page is not displaying over the entire page. It only displays in the first 100% of the page. If you scroll down, the page turns back to the normal div background-color.

I created a fiddle to help illustrate what I mean. Scroll down and click the blue text. That will make the popup window appear. Then if you scroll up you will see that the gray background-color is only displaying in the first 100% viewport, but then going back to white when you scroll down. I want the entire page to turn that gray color when clicked on.

My Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/3x42sdd8/1/

I have set the height to 100%, so I'm not sure why that isn't taking any effect on the entire page.

```
.black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.3;
    opacity:.30;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

Comment: `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: I'm sorry. I have that already in my file. I forgot to add it to it though.

Comment: Also, your position is better of `fixed` as the absolute position positions it at 0, 0 of your document, and the 100% height means it has the height of your _viewport_. Add `position: fixed` and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the position to `fixed` for your overlay, as the `absolute` will position it at `0, 0` of your *document* while the `height: 100%` gives it 100% of the height of your *viewport*. Position `fixed` fixes it to position `0,0` of your *viewport*.

Here is an example that shows you the difference between position `absolute` (red) and position `fixed` (blue):

```css
#push {
  height: 5000px;
}
#absolute, #fixed {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="push"></div>
<div id="absolute"></div>
<div id="fixed"></div>
```

Comment: I can only fix your fiddle, not your actual page - there must be something else, although I wouldn't know what because elements with position `fixed` (and two positioning values set) are always stuck to the viewport, as you can see in the snippet as well.

Comment: Never mind, it works. I was attempting to change my media query `black_overlay` instead. Thank you for the great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out - https://jsfiddle.net/3x42sdd8/2/

Just updated position

```
.black_overlay{position:fixed;}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow - you could expand a bit on _why_ this is the case, as otherwise your answer isn't very helpful to people reading this later and not having this specific implementation.